# Enable GZip for AJAX Node Express + nginx?

Tags: ajax, node.js, nginx, express, gzip

I'm trying to enable GZip for Ajax requests with content-type : text/plain. Node/Express is working behind nginx: static files are served directly with nginx, other requests are proxied to node.

Here's my nginx config:

```
http {
  ...
      gzip             on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml application/rdf+xml;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k; 
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
  ...
}
```

My app.js:

```
...
app.use(express.compress());
app.use(express['static'](globals.path.join(__dirname, "static/")));
...
```

This is how I request text/plan data:

```
$.ajax({
    url: window.location.pathname + '/content',
    type: "GET",
    // this header is NOT sent by Safari
    beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip');},
    success: function() { console.log('Success!'); }
  });
```

This is how I respond from Node side:

```
res.setHeader('Content-type','text/plain');
res.send(result.content);
```

Safari shows:

[image]

How should I enable Gzip properly?

Thank you.

Comment: your client isn't saying that it accepts gzip, maybe that's why the server isn't gzipping, your browser should send `Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate`

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Well, I try to set such header, however Safari blocks it as an unsafe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add headers to static gzip file in express/nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35774707/how-to-add-headers-to-static-gzip-file-in-express-nodejs)